# Let In Statement Error

Tags: sorting, haskell, insertion-sort

I have a problem with the following haskell statement:

```
insertSort3 xs =
    let sort3 [] ys = ys
         sort3 (x:xs) ys = sort3 xs (insert x ys)
    in sort3 xs []
```

My compiler says: parse error on input ‘=’ (The error occurs in line three).

Comment: The problem is the indentation of the second definition of sort3

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the indentation in the second line of `let`:

```
insertSort3 xs = 
 let sort3 [] ys = ys
     -- the next line should line up with the previous sort3
     sort3 (x:xs) ys = sort3 xs (insert x ys)
 in sort3 xs []
```